# How to display if a field exists in other table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I want to show/display if the product is found each transaction.

**tblProducts**

```
ID     PRODCODE    PRODDESC
1      PFX-321     MILK CHOCO
2      PDF-875     COFFEE JELLY
3      PWA-718     MILK SHAKE
```

**tblTransactions**

```
TCODE       PRODCODE
BMX2213391  PFX-321
BMX2213391  PDF-875
PDFSD92851  PDF-875
```

I want the results to display like this

```
TCODE       PRODCODE    FOUND
BMX2213391  PFX-321     YES
BMX2213391  PDF-875     YES
BMX2213391  PWA-718     NO
PDFSD92851  PFX-321     NO
PDFSD92851  PDF-875     YES
PDFSD92851  PWA-718     NO
```

I tried, INNER JOIN, FULL OUTER JOIN, LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN but I don't get the exact data I need.

Here are the queries I test.

```
SELECT * FROM tblProducts a INNER JOIN tblTransactions b ON a.PRODCODE = b.PRODCODE
SELECT * FROM tblProducts a FULL OUTER JOIN tblTransactions b ON a.PRODCODE = b.PRODCODE
SELECT * FROM tblProducts a LEFT JOIN tblTransactions b ON a.PRODCODE = b.PRODCODE
SELECT * FROM tblProducts a RIGHT JOIN tblTransactions b ON a.PRODCODE = b.PRODCODE
```

Comment: Plesae show your attempt.

Comment: [Here](http://i62.tinypic.com/28j9rw2.png) is what I have done.

Comment: Paste your query in the question.

Comment: `case when a == null || b == null then 'no' else 'yes' end` on an full join... this is pseudo code

Comment: @RadioSpace How come **a** will become null when it is a table? I come up with this `SELECT DISTINCT TCODE, a.PRODCODE, FOUND = CASE a.PRODCODE WHEN b.PRODCODE THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END FROM tblProducts a, tblTransactions b ORDER BY TCODE` but it displays incorrect values

Comment: yes and no was backwards I think. and use a or b.tcode not just tcode and `found =` can go. you have no join. the full join will return null when one table doesn't have the value so it's possible that a.prodcode = null and b.prodcode = 'something'. and this is what you test to find out if you FOUND it

Comment: I think what you are saying was already posted as an answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this works - SQLFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/65eb1/23

```
WITH AllVals AS 
(SELECT a.PRODCODE, b.TCODE
FROM tblProducts a
CROSS JOIN tblTransactions b)

SELECT DISTINCT c.PRODCODE,
  c.TCODE,
  CASE WHEN d.PRODCODE IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END AS FOUND
FROM AllVals c
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblTransactions d
ON c.PRODCODE = d.PRODCODE
AND c.TCODE = d.TCODE
```

Comment: The results to display is posted on the question.

Comment: @pvzkch Is it just the order that is different?

Comment: Your output is different. The number of records specifically.

Comment: go for it greg I am pulling out of this one

Comment: @pvzkch OK, answer updated. I think this is correct now.

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/65eb1/24

```
select DT.TCODE, DT.PRODCODE, case when (Tr2.TCODE IS null and Tr2.PRODCODE IS null) then 'No' else 'Yes' END as FOUND
 from tblTransactions Tr2 right join 
(
select distinct Tr.TCODE, p.PRODCODE               
from   tblProducts p  cross join tblTransactions Tr
) DT
on DT.PRODCODE = Tr2.PRODCODE and DT.TCODE = Tr2.TCODE;
```